# Get total of numbers from another cell / column, if they exist in another column

Tags: google-sheets

See the following [Google Sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hBcw60nrwkk-qGdLjpJKW7xnEdZJc8ryUtfZlxi1X5w/edit#gid=1289237899). In this sheet:

- In `column D` you will see I have a set of numbers which correspond to the questions that are related to a specific topic.
- In `column H` onwards, you will see that I'm mapping out those questions individually.

What I'm trying to do in pseudo is:

*"For all the questions in `column D`, find all the total available marks for them and put them in `column E` and find my scores for them and put it in `column F`"*

For example, let's assume `row 7`'s topic "Accepting engagements" only had `column D` values of of `1, 2`. I can see the available marks for Q1 is `124` and for Q2 is `15`. So, in cell `E7`, I would expect to see `139 (124 + 15)` and a `F7` value of `72 (40+32)`.

How can I do this dynamically via a formula?

What I've tried:

- `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($J:$J,1,FALSE), 0)` to get total available marks for matching questions

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Would you please summarise your research for this topic, and any attempts that you have made to solve the problem yourself. There are several ways that this could be addressed including formulas or Apps script. When you say "How can I do this "programmatically?", do you you mean that you are looking for an Apps Script solution?

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz - Apologies for not being clear, by programmatically, I meant via a formula so it's dynamic. I've updated my question to showcase a `VLOOKUP` approach I've tried.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same result, different approach:

Cell E1:
`=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(transpose(split(D7,", ",TRUE,TRUE)),$H$4:$J$101,2,0)))`
Copy down to row #22

Cell F1:
`=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(transpose(split(D7,", ",TRUE,TRUE)),$H$4:$J$101,3,0)))`
Copy down to row #22

---

BTW, Topic #7, there's a missing comma between "17" and "25".

Comment: Good spot on row `#7`!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in E7:

```
=index(mmult(--ifna(vlookup(split(D7:D22,","),H4:I101,2,0),0),
sequence(columns(split(D7:D22,",")))^0))
```

and this in F7:

```
=index(mmult(--ifna(vlookup(split(D7:D22,","),H4:J101,3,0),0),
sequence(columns(split(D7:D22,",")))^0))
```

These two formulas will produce all the results for the range D7:D22.

Essentially, we are splitting the related questions by the comma, looking them up in the table and returning the corresponding Mark/Score, then doing a row-by-row sum with MMULT().